# How to test condition with Jest in React-Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

I have to test this line of condition, but I have no idea of how can I do, everything I try to do gives error or doesn't change my percent cover test.
Basically, if there is no order, it haves to appear an message (`'There is no orders'`) in other screen (in a list), or it haves to appear (`'Received orders'`).

It is this specific condition, if you can help me:

```
       .then((responseJson) => {
          if (responseJson.length == 0) {
            this.setState({ received_order_message: 'There is no orders' });
          }
          else {
            this.setState({ received_order_message: 'There is orders' });
          }
      })
```

Here is a part of the code of interest:

```
class OrderedProducts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          orders: [''],
          buyer_orders: [''],
          refreshing: false,
          my_order_message: 'My orders',
          received_order_message: 'Received orders',
      };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.loadOrders();
    }

    loadOrders = async () => {
      const {state} = this.props.navigation;
      var token = state.params ? state.params.token : undefined;
      var user = jwt_decode(token);

      const orders_screen_path = `${process.env.ORDERS}/api/orders_screen/`;

      fetch(orders_screen_path, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
          'user_id': user.user_id,
          'token': token,
        }),
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
          console.log(responseJson);
          if (responseJson.length == 0) {
            this.setState({ received_order_message: 'There is no orders' });
          }
          else {
            this.setState({ received_order_message: 'There is orders' });
          }
          if (responseJson.length > 1) {
            responseJson.sort((order1, order2) => {
              return (order1.date - order2.date);
            }).reverse();
          }
          this.setState({ orders: responseJson });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
      });
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you handled mocking `fetch()` call? you need to fake response with empty and non-empty list to cover this block

Comment: Yess, I've made it, but this line in specif I couldn't pass.. I'll try to make what you said